# Console Hang when Incorrect UserID Password Entered to Lotus Notes Client with Java

Tags: java, passwords, lotus-notes, userid

I am writing a standalone Java application which talks to a Lotus Notes client using notes.jar. The application doesn't have access to a Domino server which is why I'm using the Lotus Notes client.

The user id file location and password are supplied by the user through my application and which then connects to the Lotus Notes client using these.

In the client I first create a session using a default ID which my application sets within the notes.ini file for the Lotus Notes client, and then switch the ID, i.e.:

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String) null, (String) null, "defaultPassword");
session.createRegistration().switchToID(userSuppliedIDFilename, userSuppliedPassword);
```

If the user-supplied password is correct, this all works fine.

If the password is wrong however, the `switchToID()` method prompts the console for the correct password:

```
The ID file being used is: CN=Test Test/=Development
Enter password (press the Esc key to abort):
```

My Java application can't respond to this console prompt so it hangs.

Is there any way to stop the prompt. i.e. get the `switchToID()` method to throw an exception when the password is wrong so that the application can return an error message to the user?

Is there a way for my application to send the `Esc` key back to the prompt so I can abort the process as indicated in the message coming back from Notes?

Is there a better way to create a client session with user-entered ID file and password?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understood, it would throw a NotesException if the session is not created successfully.

```
NotesFactory.createSession((String)null, (String)null, passwordString) throws NotesException
```

Access is granted if the password matches the Notes user ID password.
Why don't you try .. catch it

```
try {
  Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String) null, (String) null, "defaultPassword");
  if(session != null) {
    //do sth.
  }
}
catch (NotesException e) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `createSession(String)null, (String)null, passwordString)` does throw unlike the `switchToID(userId, password)` method. The only downside is that I have to update the notes.ini file on disk in order to do this prior to the login. But as long as I synchronise the notes.ini file updates, this is fine.

Comment: Well, good to hear. If that is enough, you can vote or finish the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to `userSuppliedIDFilename` without using `switchToID()` and beeing able to catch a wrong `userSuppliedPassword` this way:

```
    NotesThread.sinitThread();
    Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String) null, (String) null, "defaultPassword");
    session.setEnvironmentVar("KeyFileName", userSuppliedIDFilename, true);
    session.recycle();
    NotesThread.stermThread();
    NotesThread.sinitThread();
    try {
        session = NotesFactory.createSession((String) null, (String) null, userSuppliedPassword);
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // wrong password for userSuppliedIDFilename
        // ask user for correct password... 
    }
```

Comment: Great!, This worked for me, but I replaced 2nd statement:
`Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String) null, (String) null, "defaultPassword");`
by this one:
`Session session = NotesFactory.createSession();`